# ARM A7 Linux raw interrupt handling possible?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, irq

I'd like to write an open-sourced core driver for controlling stepper motors in Linux. In this case, especially for 3D-Printers.

The basic idea is that the driver reserves pins on one IO port, and then manipulates those pins at once. It receives a buffer full of "toggle this, toggle that" values, and then emits those to the port, using a hardware timer.

Now the question is: Is there any way to handle a specific hardware interrupt as fast as possible?

The chip in question is an Allwinner H3, and I am using the TMR1 resource of said chip (IRQ 51). I can use it just fine, and it works as an interrupt as well:

```
static irqreturn_t stepCore_timer_interrupt(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
        writel(TMR1_IRQ_PEND, TMR_IRQ_ST_VREG);
        icnt++;

        porta_state = readl(PA_VDAT);
        porta_state &= porta_mask;

        if(icnt & 0x00000001)
        {
            porta_state |= 0x00000001;
        }

        writel(porta_state, PA_VDAT);

        return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static struct irqaction stepCore_timer_irq = {
        .name = "stepCore_timer",
        .flags = IRQF_DISABLED | IRQF_NOBALANCING , IRQF_PERCPU,
        .handler = stepCore_timer_interrupt,
        .dev_id = NULL,
};

static void stepCore_timer_interrupt_setup(void)
{
    int ret;
    u32 val;

    writel( 24000000, TMR1_INTV_VALUE_VREG );
    writel( ( TMR1_MODE_CONTINUOUS | TMR1_CLK_PRES_1 | TMR1_CLK_SRC_OSC24M ), TMR1_CTRL_VREG );

    ret = setup_irq(SUNXI_IRQ_TIMER1, &stepCore_timer_irq);
    if (ret)
            printk("%s: ERROR: failed to install irq %d\n", __func__, SUNXI_IRQ_TIMER1);
    else
            printk("%s: irq %d installed\n", __func__, SUNXI_IRQ_TIMER1);

    ret = irq_set_affinity_hint(SUNXI_IRQ_TIMER1, cpumask_of(3));
    if (ret)
            printk("%s: ERROR: failed to set irq affinity for irq %d\n", __func__, SUNXI_IRQ_TIMER1);
    else
            printk("%s: set irq affinity for irq %d\n", __func__, SUNXI_IRQ_TIMER1);
    /* Enable timer0 interrupt */
    val = readl(TMR_IRQ_EN_VREG);
    writel(val | TMR1_IRQ_EN, TMR_IRQ_EN_VREG);

}
```

TMR1 is otherwise unused (in fact, I had to add it myself) and so far works. However, there is quite some latency in handling the rather simple IRQ routine. Since I want to produce some code that is usable for a 3D printer, I very much like a more "stable" timer interrupt.

So, my question is: Is there any way to have a very short IRQ routine in Linux that has the highest possible priority? Or even doesn't care about the Linux scheduler at all, and just "does it's thing"? Basically a raw IRQ handler, ignoring what Linux thinks it should be?

The core it runs on is dedicated to just that task, anyways. The handler will be as short as possible: fetch an u32 from an array, write that to the port, done.

Preferably I would like to have something that just ignores the remainder of Linux all together. Yes, I know that that isn't the way to do it. But this is meant for a rather special case, so I have no qualms with adapting the regular kernel sources to suit those needs.

Oh, that reminds me, the kernel is 3.4.112 with the suitable preempt-rt patches.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Greetings,

Chris

Comment: Have you had a look at the RTAI kernel? Thet drives stuff like linux-cnc and should easily cope with your timing requirements.

Comment: I found referneces to the RTAI kernel, yes. But the rather sad issue is that the stuff for Allwinner chips is only partially in the mainstream kernel. Th H3 is non-existant there. As such, i have to patch myself through the old 3.4.39 kernel, which i got up to 3.4.112, and then up to the preempt-rt version of that.

Comment: Also, i have no need for some sophisticated RT functionality. All i want (if that is even possible) is that one IRQ in the GIC is handled on the bare metal. In this case, IRQ 51 (for TMR1), with little to no kernel interaction at all.

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear enough (english isn't my mother-tongue, so there ...) In the above code snippet, there is:

setup_irq(SUNXI_IRQ_TIMER1, &stepCore_timer_irq);

This sets up an IRQ in the linux kernel. (SUNXI_IRQ_TIMER1 is slot 51 in the GIC for that chip. Basically, all i want is that &stepCore_timer_irq is called by the GIC without any IRQ handling stuff from Limux involved.

Greetings,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general solution to this issue. You can write a kernel module which will overwrite the existing interrupt handling routine and will be replaced by your own routine, where you can handle your irq of interest and redirect all the irq to the existing kernel interrupt handling routine. It's possible for x86 arch where you will get low level CPU instructions to get the existing address of interrupt description routine (`lidt`). I believe it should be possible for ARM too. Now, Linux has technique of CPU isolation `isolcpus` by utilizing this technique you can take a CPU out of scheduler domain i.e. no task will be scheduled on that particular CPU, until you specify a task to be run on that particular CPU  (using taskset). After you take a CPU out of scheduler domain you can take help of the technique of affine a interrupt to that isolated CPU,  you can do it via `/proc/irq/IRQ_NUMBER/smp_affinity`. Now all of your interrupt will be handled by this isolated CPU and 100% dedicated to that interrupt. And with your own IRQ routine you have full control over the interrupt handling.

Hopefully this will help!

Comment: Do you now about any example of how to overwrite the existing interrupt handling under Linux on ARM (A7)?  Any hint?
I tried to isolate the cpu, but some interrupts are locked to specific cores, making the isolation only partial.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I was only familiar with x86 based examples and that was also like ~15 years back. But if you have your own driver where you handling the IRQ yourself then it shouldn't be that complicated either. And the cpu isolation technique is only for task (software) level isolation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using FIQ for that. We have a blog post about it:
http://free-electrons.com/blog/fiq-handlers-in-the-arm-linux-kernel/